# FTP connection error with one service provider

Tags: windows, networking, ftp, port, debug

I’ve had FTP access to a number of websites for some years using Dreamweaver on a Vista PC with Norton 360.

I’ve just changed to a Windows 10 PC with Norton 360 and transfer the Dreamweaver application and the website settings to this new PC.

Now I can connect to all the websites using FTP with the transferred settings except for a site hosted by Heart Internet which gives the error message -

> An FTP error occurred – cannot make connection to host. Your login or
>   password is incorrect.

Freshly entering the username, password etc does not resolve the problem – I downloaded and installed FileZilla to try another approach but that also failed. 
Having encountered the problem, I reconnected the Vista PC to the internet but that also failed to connect even though I had had no previous problems.

Other people who also maintain the Heart site are not having problems.

From an article on this forum, I tried to access port 21 using DOS ‘`telnet mydomain.co.uk 21`’ – this failed with the Heart domain but was successful with my other domains. This suggests to me that for some reason the Heart server is ‘blocking’ me but their response to date is to re-advise the username, password, & port.

I’ve seen on-line advice for checking the connection path with a Linux system – does anyone have any suggestions for a way forward with a Window ?

Thanks in advance.

Debugging in FileZilla gives:

> Status:   Resolving address of ftp.mywebsite.com
>
> Status:   Connecting to xx.xxx.xx.xx:21...
>
> Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
>
> Response: 220 FTP server ready
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
>
> Command:  USER myusername
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
>
> Response: 331 Password required for myusername
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
>
> Command:  PASS ***********
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
>
> Response: 530 Login failed. Please verify the username and password
>   supplied, and that FTP has been unlocked. Check your control panel or
>   contact support for more information.
>
> Trace:    CControlSocket::DoClose(1094)
>
> Trace:    CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
>
> Trace:    CControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
>
> Error:    Critical error: Could not connect to server
>
> Trace:    CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(1094)

Comment: You can try to enable debugging in filezilla and see if you can get some more information. Here is how: http://ccm.net/faq/28699-filezilla-display-the-debug-menu. To check more, you can try to connect from another network and try resetting your ftp username/password.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the debug to the original - this appears to me to suggest the password is incorrect - or is there another possible answer ?

Comment: you can try doing what the log says. `Login failed. Please verify the username and password supplied, and that FTP has been unlocked. Check your control panel or contact support for more information.` Go to your control panel and see if ftp is unlocked and reset the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enabling `debugging` in filezilla it is possible to get some more information on the problem. The option is available under *"Edit"  > Settings > File editing > Debug*.

As from the debug log you have posted:

> Response: 530 Login failed. Please verify the username and password
>   supplied, and that FTP has been unlocked. Check your control panel or
>   contact support for more information.

It is possible that your password is incorrect, then you can try resetting it from the control panel.

Another possibility is the FTP is locked. Which is a security measure implemented by some providers to prevent hacking. It blocks the ip address from where repeated failed attempt is made. I suspect your ip address is blocked. Log into your control panel and see if you can unlock the ip yourself or may be you will need to contact your provider. The feature is called **FTP Locking**.

Comment: Many thanks, problem solved. 

The main person who maintains the site had changed the Control Panel setting some time ago without realising the consequences. Without FileZilla debugging I couldn't prove it wasn't the new PC.